# What is the "Ag" shown as background of the box Constraints of the panel "size inspector" of Xcode 6 or 7?

Tags: ios, xcode, constraints

In Interface Builder of XCode 6 or 7 on the right Inspector panel, sometimes in the background of the box Constraint is shown the text "Ag", even if there is no error (red) notification in the constraints.
What does it means? 
[image: Box Constraint]

Comment: You'll have to provide a screenshot or something. I'm not sure what you're referring to. Use CMD-SHIFT-4 to create a screenshot of a specific area of your screen.

Comment: I've added the link "Box Constraint" to the screenshot.

Comment: Given the dotted line beneath it (representing the *baseline*), it looks like sample text to show the extents of the font.

Comment: To complete @trojanfoe comment: It helps for text to keep in mind where is the baseline and shows characters that goes above (uppercase) and underneath (like a "g" in lowercase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Ag" appears if a text is associated with the ui element. For example a title text for an UIButton. As others already mentioned, I think it's a helper feature for text alignments.

Caution: If you deal with the language orientations (e.g. right-to-left) a text in a title field sometimes interferes with the auto layout features of the interface builders. I once had the phenomena that the auto layout change for the right-to-left orientation places a button some points more to the right as I intended. The reason was a forgotten text in the title field. After deleting that text the "Ag" disappears and the button was placed as I intended.